# When using --negotiate with curl on windows, SSL/TLS handshake fails

Tags: windows, curl, kerberos, ntlm, negotiate

When using --negotiate (or ntlm) with curl on windows, SSL/TSL handshake fails despite having a valid kerberos ticket cached on my windows 10 (shown below). The same logic and commands works without any issue in Unix/Linux.  Any idea/help on how to resolve this issue?

Klist details:

```
$: Klist
Client: username @ XXXX.XXX
        Server: cifs/XXXXXXX.XXX @ XXXXXXX.XXX
        KerbTicket Encryption Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticket Flags XXXXXX -> forwardable renewable pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Start Time: 8/27/2020 9:46:36 (local)
        End Time:   8/27/2020 19:46:33 (local)
        Renew Time: 9/27/2020 9:46:33 (local)
        Session Key Type: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cache Flags: 0
        Kdc Called: XXXXXXXXX.XXX
```

curl command using ntlm or negotiate  details:

```
>curl --ntlm -u : https://XXXXX.XXX -v
OR
>curl --negotiate -u : https://XXXXX.XXX -v
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xxxx.xxx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port xxx (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxxx.xxx port xxx (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 186 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 186 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 1024
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5120 length 5120
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 817
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 5937 length 6144
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 51
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 51 length 6144
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.xxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 915
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 915 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 852
* schannel: decrypted data added: 852
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 852 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 34
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 34 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 5
* schannel: decrypted data added: 5
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 857 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 857 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 857
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 401
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< X-Application-Context: Apixxxxx:x
< X-RateLimit-Limit-Api_login_anonymous: 1000
< X-RateLimit-Remaining-Api_login_anonymous: 999
< X-RateLimit-Reset-Apixxx_login_anonymous: 0
< X-xxxxx-xxx: xxxxx.xxx
< Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2020 19:50:12 GMT
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Please login with your Windows account"
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=xxx ; includeSubDomains
< TraceId: 5f480e7427f78fd5406fcbef0abf8e6c
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host xxx.xxx left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://xxx.xxx/login'
* Found bundle for host xxx.xxx: 0xxxxxxxxx [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host xxx.xxx
* Connected to xxx.xxx (xx.xx.xxx.xx) port xxx (#0)
* Server auth using Negotiate with user ' '
> GET /login HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.xxx
> Authorization: Negotiate xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 814
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 814 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 751
* schannel: decrypted data added: 751
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 751 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 34
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 34 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 5
* schannel: decrypted data added: 5
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 756 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 756 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 756
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 401
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< X-Application-Context: Apixxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:x
< X-RateLimit-Limit-Apixxx_login_anonymous: 1000
< X-RateLimit-Remaining-Apixxx_login_anonymous: 999
< X-RateLimit-Reset-Apixxx_login_anonymous: 0
< X-XXXX-xxx: xxxx.xxx
< Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2020 19:50:12 GMT
< Expires: 0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=xxx ; includeSubDomains
< TraceId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host xxx.xxx left intact

>curl --version
curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL
```

Comment: The CURL command output using ntlm or negotiate details you posted looks like it actually *succeeded*, not failed, based on seeing this: "schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 3/3)", "schannel: stored credential handle in session cache" and "Connection #0 to host xxx.xxx left intact".

Comment: @T-Heron  I was referring to '* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with xxx.xxx port xxx (step 2/3)* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data'.   Any recommendation how to resolve this or what can cause getting 401 error?

Comment: I'm a little unsure about this.  But, even though it fails at step 2/3, it does show shortly thereafter succeeded at 3/3.  Seems like it tried one cipher at 2/3 which didn't work (I'm guessing the cipher is the cause here, as the failure reason in this step), but then the flow tried a different cipher which did work at step 3/3.  The cipher which failed in Windows is not present on the Linux instance you are using, so it looks cleaner on that side.  This is my best guess.  Familiar with this stuff, but not an expert at it....